# Modeling User Behaviour Using Weka

Tags: java, analytics, weka

How to Model a User Behavior using Weka. I am working on a Analytics Java Web application which needs to predict the behavior of an user based upon his visits/products views in an eCommerce application. The data set I have is

UserId, Page Visited, Time Spent on Page

Based upon the above parameters, I need to get a Prediction score for the probability the the User shall buy that product. I have tried playing out with Weka but did not know how and where to start. My requirement is that the application should be flexible enough to apply various Regression Algorithms/ or any Predictive Analysis. Is that achievable using Weka.

If not, Is there any other ready to use library to fulfill my requirement. Any help/guidance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is achiveable in WEKA, as log as you have your data manually classified with the target class. What you need is to previously know if the user purchases the product or not.

You need to have a dataset with the predictions, like this ARFF file:

```
@relation UserModelDataset

@attribute UserId numeric
@attribute PageVisitedId numeric
@attribute TimeSpent numeric
@attribute PurchaseClass {no,yes}

@data
1,1,0.3,no
1,2,8.1,yes
2,1,0.5,no
// ...
```

Apart from having the class in order to predict, I advise to take into account:

- The `UserId` attribute should be stripped during classification if you want to generalize over users.
- The `PageVisitedId` attribute is an ID, You can use instead the title or text of the page, the URL, and probably many other attributes.

Comment: Thank you so much Jose Maria, I need to implement the analysis on multiple web applications, hence userId cannot be stripped and it is a alphanumeric value, I have tried analyzing a very minute dataset using   Bayesian classifier but got the error "Cannot handle Numeric Class". I have a novice to Weka and want your guidance on getting familiar with it, especially Weka integration with Java. can you please suggest a sample application or a tutorial, which would be helpful for me to get familiar with Weka.

Comment: I see the point regarding the UserId, in fact you may want yo perfom "user-centric" learning: an specific model per user.

Regarding the Bayesian classifier, if you want to predict the time the user will spend (instead of the fact of purchasing, which is a nominal class), you have a regression problem - similar to classification, but with a numeric class. There are several algorithms in WEKA for that, like Logistic Regression.

Regarding a good tutorial, well it takes some time but the videos of the WEKA MOOC are great: http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/mooc/dataminingwithweka/.